# What's the difference between the two in meaning?

Tags: sentence-meaning

What's the difference between the two in meaning?

> 1. The mayor has a new bridge built.
> 2. The mayor has built a new bridge.

Comment: What do you think about these two? Show some efforts. And, in any case, it's *mayor has..*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first sentence means that *the mayor had people build that bridge for him*.
The second sentence (correct form: The mayor has built a new bridge.) means that *the mayor built the bridge him self*.